# Principal value of $1/x$ and few questions about complex analysis in Peskin's QFT textbook

Tags: mathematical-physics, notation, integration, complex-numbers, dirac-delta-distributions

When I learn QFT, I am bothered by many problems in complex analysis.

1. $$\frac{1}{x-x_0+i\epsilon}=P\frac{1}{x-x_0}-i\pi\delta(x-x_0)$$

I can't understand why $1/x$ can have a principal value because it's not a multivalued function. I'm very confused. And when I learned complex analysis, I've not watched [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem), can anybody tell me where I can find this formula's proof.

2. $$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x+i\epsilon)=P\frac{1}{x}-i\pi\delta(x)$$
3. 

And I also find this formula. Seemingly $f(x)$ has a branch cut, then
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_Z^{\infty}dz^{\prime}\frac{{\rm Im} f(z^{\prime})}{z^{\prime}-z}$$
Can anyone can tell the whole theorem and its proof, and what it wants to express.
[image]

Now I am very confused by these formula, because I haven't read them in any complex analysis book and never been taught how to handle an integral with branch cut. Can anyone give me the whole proof and where I can consult?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are two completely unrelated meanings of the term "principal value". The kind referred to here is the [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), which assigns values to otherwise undefined improper integrals. This has nothing to do with the [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value) you had in mind, which is for selecting single-valued branches of multi-valued functions. I know, it's stupid. You'd think someone would have fixed all these weird ambiguities by now, but alas math is not French.

Comment: @DavidH Thanks a lot! Then the last question, can you give me some clues?

Comment: @user34669 I think the last expression goes by the name of "Kramers-Kronig" relation, it is a way to express a complex function in its real or imaginary part. So with either the real or imaginary part, you can reconstruct the whole function. For a proof, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations

Comment: More answers are at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/10327

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first equation,
$$\frac{1}{x-x_0+i\epsilon}=P\frac{1}{x-x_0}-i\pi\delta(x-x_0)$$
is actually a shorthand notation for its correct full form, which is
$$\underset{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}{\lim}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(x)}{x-x_0+i\epsilon}\,dx=P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(x)}{x-x_0}\,dx-i\pi f(x_0)$$
This is valid for functions which are analytic in the upper half-plane and vanish fast enough such that the integral can be constructed by an infinite semicircular contour.

This can be proved by constructing a semicircular contour in the upper half-plane of radius $\rho\rightarrow\infty$, with an indent placed at $x_0$, making use of the residue theorem adapted to semi-circular arcs. See Saff, Snider Fundamentals of Complex Analysis, Section 8.5 Question 8.

The third one is the Kramers-Kronig relation, as Funzies mentioned.